# How to pass the variable value which is a function to the calling

Tags: reactjs, jsx

I am iterating the array which will setup my React `input` component. The problem that I am facing is I don't know how to pass the `onEmailFilled` as a function to the `handle_changes`.

```
const inputComponentArray= [{id_name : "signin_email", input_label : "Email", input_type : "email", handle_changes: "{onEmailFilled}"}, {id_name : "signin_password", input_label : "Password", input_type : "password", handle_changes: "{onPasswordFilled}"}]

class Test extends Component{
render()
{
  {
    inputComponentArray.map((object => {
    return 
      <VerticalInputComponent
        id_name={object.id_name}
        input_label={object.input_label}
        input_type={object.input_type}
        handle_changes={object.handle_changes} //this is not working because it received a string instead of a function
      />
    }
   ))
 }
}
```

}

How do I this or is there a better way of doing this? I am using `map` is because I want to make a dynamic form page.

This is in the `VerticalInputComponent.js` which is a different page.

```
<input
  id={this.props.id_name}
  name={this.props.id_name}
  className="input-reset ba b--black-20 pa2 mb2 db w-100 lh-copy lh-copy-l lh-copy-m lh-copy-ns"
  type={this.props.input_type}
  autoComplete="on"
  onChange={this.props.handle_changes}
/>
```

Comment: Would you mind providing your onEmailFiled function? It looks like you're trying to pass it as part of the inputComponentArray, but that's simply passing in a string reference

Comment: I am passing the handle_changes from my container file to the VerticalInputComponent's onChange. I hope this will help you understand my question

Comment: @calvert `inputComponentArray` is not passing a function associated with the key `handle_changes` but a string `{onEmailFilled}`. You should replace the string with an actual function. `inputComponentArray =[{handle_changes: function() {...}}]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assign the function reference directly to the object property, without executing it. For example:

```
const onEmailFilled = () => {
    console.log("onEmailFilled called");
};

const inputComponentArray = [
    {
        id_name: "signin_email",
        /*...*/
        handle_changes: onEmailFilled
    }
];

/*...*/

inputComponentArray.map(object => (
    <VerticalInputComponent
        id_name={object.id_name}
        input_label={object.input_label}
        input_type={object.input_type}
        handle_changes={object.handle_changes}
    />
));
```

Depending on where the function is coming from you have to add the reference to it, but without executing it (without adding `()`)

- From props: `handle_changes: this.props.onEmailFilled`
- From class method: `handle_changes: this.onEmailFilled`
- From constant: `handle_changes: onEmailFilled`

Comment: `const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
  return {
    onEmailFilled: event => dispatch(userLoggedIn(event.target.value)),
    onPasswordFilled: event => dispatch(userLoggedIn(event.target.value))
  };
};`

Comment: My onEmailFilled is in the mapDispatchToProps actually, so how do I pass it in this case?

Comment: @calvert I guess in that case it belongs to props? If so: `handle_changes: this.props.onEmailFilled`.

Comment: Yes, you are right. Thank you so much for helping me solve this.

Answer (score 0):

This is really a question of how to store a function in an object then pass it to an event handler.

Here is a demonstration on how you can do this:

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = {
          myInput: [
            {
              id_name: "signin_email",
              input_label: "Email",
              input_type: "email",
              handle_changes: this.onEmailChanged,
              input_value: ""
            }
          ]
      };
  }
  
  onEmailChanged = (e) => {
    const myInputNew = this.state.myInput;
    myInputNew[0].input_value = e.target.value;
    this.setState({ myInput: myInputNew });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <input
          id={this.state.myInput[0].id_name}
          name={this.state.myInput[0].id_name}
          className="input-reset ba b--black-20 pa2 mb2 db w-100 lh-copy lh-copy-l lh-copy-m lh-copy-ns"
          type={this.state.myInput[0].input_type}
          value={this.state.myInput[0].input_value}
          onChange={this.state.myInput[0].handle_changes}
        />
        <div>Your input: {this.state.myInput[0].input_value}</div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

// Render it
ReactDOM.render(
  <App/>,
  document.getElementById("react")
);
```

```html
<div id="react"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: `const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
  return {
    onEmailFilled: event => dispatch(userLoggedIn(event.target.value)),
    onPasswordFilled: event => dispatch(userLoggedIn(event.target.value))
  };
};`

Comment: My onEmailFilled is in the mapDispatchToProps redux, what should I do in this case?

Comment: Can you give an example of how you're mapping your dispatch to props so that we have a better idea of how you're referring to your function?

Comment: Thank you for the effort Shawn Andrews & Ariel Salem, Alvaro already helped me in solving this. It is a mistake that I made because I just started building my first app using react redux.

Comment: In that case, use `handle_changes={this.props.onEmailFilled}`